# NSTableView with more than one UI element in NSCell (like Transmission)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

How would I make an `NSCell` with more than one UI element in it and display it in an `NSTableView`? For `NSCells` with a single value I could implement `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` but I don't know how to do this for `NSCells` with more than one. At the moment I have an `NSView` in an `NSCollectionView` and all the elements are bound to an `NSArrayController`. But I'd rather have an `NSTableView` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the primary value in the `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method, and then set up the cell further in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`.

Either that, or you create a custom `NSCell` subclass that can customize itself based on the `objectValue` that you give it.

Comment: If I use the last option, would I need to subclass the NSCell's `objectValue` or only its `setObjectValue:` ?

Comment: Nevermind, that was a stupid question. Of course I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to JAListView for table and outline views in my Mac apps: https://github.com/joshaber/JAListView

It has the advantage of using NSViews for table items instead of NSCells, allowing for greater freedom in implementing your design.

There's a few other alternatives out there too trying to solve similar gaps in NSTableView and its subclasses:
http://groups.google.com/group/cocoa-unbound/browse_thread/thread/87b2a1b5725eac05